# Typescript: Extending from {}

Tags: typescript

Given:

```
class A<T extends {
  [k: string]: any
}> {
  private model: T

  constructor(model: T = {}) {
    this.model = model
  }
}
```

Why do i got an error stating

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Doesn't {} is assignable to

> { [k: string]: any }

Thank you.

Comment: This feels like a bug. Did you check the typescript issues list?

Comment: Constraints are lower bounds, not upper ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct error.

Your class says that this code is legal:

```
type MyType = {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

const c = new A<MyType>();
```

But now you have an `A` whose `model` value *does not have* the required `a` and `b` properties.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21521). The solution to issue is as below

```
class A<T extends {
    [k: string]: any
}> {
    private model: T

    constructor(model: T = <T>{}) {
        this.model = model
    }
}
```

Using type cast in constructor is essential `model: T = <T>{}`

Then you cn instantiate `class A` with just

```
var instA = new A();
// instA.model will be {}
```

You may also read [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400) It has links and discussions about similar issues.

Comment: Yes, i noticed this when trying to solve it. But i think it shouldn't be the answer because why would {} isn't assignable to {[k: string]?: any} in the first place.

Comment: I've made edit with lnks to github issue about this case